# Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions

Tags: flutter, dart

I extracted a method, so I would not have to type out the same lines of code over and over again. The method is a container with set colors and a fixed height. I want the Text inside the Container to be inputted manually; I do not want it to be a fixed value. I tried doing so, but then I get the error posted in the title, and I am not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code; the error is when I call the String 'name' in the Text Widget.

```dart
    class ContainerShowingDifferentAlgsets extends StatelessWidget {
    ContainerShowingDifferentAlgsets({required this.name});
    final String name;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 50.0,
      color: Colors.white24,
      child: const Center(
        child: Text(
          name, // <-- THIS is where the error occurs.
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
        ),
      ),
    );
       }
     }
```

I tried adding a final item to the method. Thought it would allow me to manually input the Text of the container, but it did not.

Comment: Just remove the `const` keyword before the **Center** widget

Comment: You get that error because you have declared the **Center** widget and marked it as const, so its child must also contain a constant value.  A value can be const if it can be determined at compile time (before your code starts running). The *name* assigned to the **Text** widget is not known until runtime (when your code starts running) hence it cannot be marked as const

Comment: Thank you! It fixed it, and I'll be sure to keep that in mind.